# Правильный SQL запрос UPDATE на PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Как написать правильный запрос на обновление определенных слов в таблице wp_post?

Код, который обновляет слова:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово1', 'замена1');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово2', 'замена2');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово3', 'замена3');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово4', 'замена4');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово5', 'замена5');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово6', 'замена6');
```

Этот код работает в PHPmyAdmin но когда я делаю php файл который подключается к базе и отправляет SQL запрос, то тут уже мой код не работает я обращался к своему ХОСТЕРУ они говорят что нужно использовать "mysql_multi_query" что бы отправлять такой запрос пожалуйста кто нибудь напишите код как отправить такой запрос через этот multi_query я пробовал по мануалу php.net не получилось!
У меня получился такой код

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$mysqli = new mysqli(тут мои данные);

/* проверка соединения */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$query  = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово1', 'замена1');";
$query .= "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово2', 'замена2');";
$query .= "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово3', 'замена3');";

/* запускаем мультизапрос */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
do {
    /* получаем первый результирующий набор */
    if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    /* печатаем разделитель */
    if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
        printf("Все ок.\n");
    }
} while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* закрываем соединение */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Какая у вас конкретная ошибка в этом коде?

Comment: Ошибки нету просто не чего не меняется он же должен заменять а он не меняет

Comment: Вы в базу смотрели после выполнения кода? Включен ли вывод всех ошибок? В логах ошибок сервера тоже пусто?

Comment: И зачем у вас в коде цикл? Вы разве `SELECT...` выполняли, чтобы результат в цикле смотреть?

Comment: Пожалуйста не могли бы вы мне написать правильный код

Comment: Или подсказать как включить эти ошибки? В логах сервера это где смотреть или это только тех поддержка скажет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А я предлагаю все запросы скомпоновать в один. То есть вместо

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово1', 'замена1');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово2', 'замена2');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово3', 'замена3');
```

пишем один запрос

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
   SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово1', 'замена1'),
       post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово2', 'замена2'),
       post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово3', 'замена3');
```

Все `REPLACE` выполняются за один раз.

Пример http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9442/1

P.S. А по вашему коду скажу (в дополнении к комментарию): В цикле вам там ни чего не вернет, так как вы выполняете **UPDATE** запрос, а не выборку данных через **SELECT**.

**UPD**

@msi в комментарии написал, что один столбец изменять несколько раз в UPDATE нельзя. Правда доказательств не предоставил. Тогда перепишу запрос по другому с вложенными REPLACE

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
   SET post_content = REPLACE(
                          REPLACE(
                              REPLACE(post_content, 'слово1', 'замена1'),
                          'слово2', 'замена2'),
                      'слово3', 'замена3');
```

Пример http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e15f9b/1

**UPD2**

Протестировал утверждение @msi о том, что нельзя в UPDATE несколько раз менять поле на реальной базе mysql через phpmyadmin.

**Первый вариант из моего ответа прекрасно работает!**

Comment: Почему я вставил ваш код но он тоже не работает? [ссылка](http://pastie.org/10439751)

Comment: @МихаилВолков, вы мне так и не ответили еще в комментарии к вопросу: вы в базе смотрите изменения после выполнения кода?

Comment: Я не понимаю Вас как это смотрели я же меняю значение в записях WordPress и там не чего не меняется зачем смотреть в Базу что же я там увижу?

Comment: От MySQL всего можно ожидать, но в одном update запрещено менять один столбец несколько раз.

Comment: @МихаилВолков, перед `$result_set->close();` (то есть после выполнения запроса) сделайте вывод ошибки: `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);`

Comment: @msi, покажите где это написано в документации?

Comment: @Visman [Вот что получилось](http://pastie.org/10439798) Он мне просто вывел строчку Errormessage: больше не чего, а слово не поменялось...

Comment: @МихаилВолков, вот этот код с одним UPDATE и REPLACE у вас выполняется? Замена происходит?

Comment: @Visman, какую документацию вы имели в виду?
Я мало использую MySQL, и там стараюсь обходиться стандартными средставами. А стандарт запрещает. Чтобы нарушать стандарт, должны быть веские основания. В данном случае их нет. Посмотрите моё решение это проблемы.

Comment: @msi, я написал аналогичное исправление у себя, зачем мне на ваше смотреть? Но первый вариант тоже работает, по этому я и прошу у вас ссылку на то, что его нельзя использовать.

Comment: @msi, прочитайте второе обновление моего ответа :Р

Comment: Вы пытаетесь убедить меня, что в MySQL это возможно. Значит я просто минусую MySQL. SQL Server на это скажет: "Имя столбца "a" указано несколько раз в предложении SET или в списке столбцов инструкции INSERT. В одном предложении нельзя присвоить столбцу несколько значений. Исправьте предложение так, чтобы значение столбца изменялось только один раз. Если предложение обновляет или вставляет столбцы в представление, то при использовании псевдонимов столбцов дубликаты в коде могут быть скрыты."
Я лишний раз убеждаюсь, что использовать MySQL для изучения SQL - не лучший вариант.

Comment: @msi, в вопросе ясно прописан тег `mysql` если вы не заметили.

Comment: @Visman Пожалуйста посмотрите все ли я делаю правильно у меня не получается та же одно слово поменять почему то! [ссылка](http://pastie.org/10439884)

Comment: @МихаилВолков, `$result_set->close();` уберите.

Comment: @Visman Я убрал как вы сказали но все равно не работает что делать?

Comment: @МихаилВолков, трясите теперь службу поддержки вашего хостера. Может найдут вашу ошибку.

Comment: @Visman может дело в скобках я уже не знаю на что думать я использую query(" - тут двойные а потом ординарные может в этом дело?

Comment: @Visman Спасибо большое буду теперь доставать их но в коде точно все ок да же?

Comment: @МихаилВолков, запрос окружен двойными, внутри одинарные. Верно.

Comment: @Visman Верно. Спасибо теперь точно буду доставать техническую поддержку

Comment: @Visman, заметил, но зачем использовать нестандартный прием, который не будет работать при смене платформы, если есть решение в рамках стандарта.

Comment: @Visman Спасибо вам еще раз ваш код работает... Моя проблема решилась хостинг проверил и добавил вот это `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");`

Answer (score 1):

Зачем искать проблему там, где её нет:

```
 UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(post_content,
 'слово1', 'замена1'),
    'слово2', 'замена2'),
    'слово3', 'замена3');
```

Ну, и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

> они говорят что нужно использовать "mysql_multi_query"

они бредят.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$query[] = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово1', 'замена1');";
$query[] = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово2', 'замена2');";
$query[] = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'слово3', 'замена3');";
foreach($query as $q) $mysqli->query($q);
```

Ошибки смотреть в логах. Предварительно убедившись, что логирование в принципе включено.

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не используйте множественные запросы (`mysql_multi_query`), иначе это чревато серьезной SQL инъекцией.

Вам нужно каждый запрос выполнить отдельно. Либо статично прописать выполнение всех запросов, либо в цикле.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте все запросы написать в одну строку разделяя запятыми, должно помочь.
Хостер ругаеться адекватно, и он прав, Вы создаете неопраданно большую нагрузку на базу, множеством точечных запросов.